# Finding the value of each letter in a word using map and reduce

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, reduce

I have a function wordScore(word, scoreList). The word is a string that consists of only letters and scoreList is a list containing the value of each letter in the alphabet:

```
scoreList = [ ["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["c", 3], ["d", 2], ["e", 1], 
            ["f", 4], ["g", 2], ["h", 4], ["i", 1], ["j", 8], 
            ["k", 5], ["l", 1], ["m", 3], ["n", 1], ["o", 1], ["p", 3], 
            ["q", 10], ["r", 1], ["s", 1], ["t", 1], ["u", 1], ["v", 4], 
            ["w", 4], ["x", 8], ["y", 4], ["z", 10] ]
```

I have to find the total score of a word and then return it using map and reduce. Example:

```
wordScore('agile', scoreList)
>>> 6
```

I believe that I am not able to do this problem because I am not sure what map does. I would really appreciate some help.

Second Problem:
So now I am given a list of letters that(lets say listOfwords = `["a", "am", "at", "apple", "bat", "bar", "babble", "can", "foo", "spam", "spammy", "zzyzva"]`) When I input a list of letters in scoreList(Rack) (such as `scoreList(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p"])` then it should output all possible words that can be made with the letters that are in listOfwords. So basically it would be like:

```
>>> scoreList(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p"])
[['a', 1], ['am', 4], ['at', 2], ['spam', 8]]
>>> scoreList(["a", "s", "m", "o", "f", "o"])
[['a', 1], ['am', 4], ['foo', 6]]
```

This is my code so far:

```
def scoreList(Rack):
    test = [x for x in Dictionary if all(y in Rack for y in x)]
    return test
```

However when I run this it only gives me the words that can be made with the letters and I'm not sure how to get the score for each word. Could I possibly use wordScore? Also same restriction apply.

Comment: Can you transform `scoreList` into a dict? such as: `{'a': 1,
 'b': 3,
 'c': 3,
 'd': 2,
 'e': 1,
 'f': 4,
 'g': 2,
 'h': 4,
 'i': 1,
 'j': 8,
 'k': 5,
 'l': 1,
 'm': 3,
 'n': 1,
 'o': 1,
 'p': 3,
 'q': 10,
 'r': 1,
 's': 1,
 't': 1,
 'u': 1,
 'v': 4,
 'w': 4,
 'x': 8,
 'y': 4,
 'z': 10}`

Comment: Sadly no it must remain a list. If I could it would be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map creates a sequence by applying a function to every items in a sequence:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x + 1, [1, 2, 3])
[2, 3, 4]
```

So to solve your problem:

If you can use `dict`, loop over all letters in word and map it to its score. Then sum all letter scores with reduce:

```
def wordScore(word, score_list):
    score_dict = dict(score_list)
    letter_scores = map(lambda letter: score_dict[letter], word)
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, letter_scores)
```

If you cannot, loop over all letters in score list and multiply each score by number of occurence of letter in word, then sum all letter scores with reduce:

```
def wordScore(word, score_list):
    letter_scores = map(
        lambda letter_score: word.count(letter_score[0]) * letter_score[1], 
        score_list
    )
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, letter_scores)
```

Read [map documentation in python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map)

Comment: Hey man thanks again for your help. I was wondering if you can help me with a second problem. I have edited the original post with the details.